# Google App Engine: Cron handler is called by cron, but no code is run

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, handler

I have a following problem. I have defined a cron job in Google App Engine, but my get method is not called (or to be precise it is called every other time - if I run it manually it doesn't do anything at the first time, but at the second it works flawlessly). This is output from logging for the call made by cron:

```
2011-07-04 11:39:08.500 /suggestions/ 200 489ms 70cpu_ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
0.1.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2011:11:39:08 -0700] "GET /suggestions/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "bazinga-match.appspot.com" ms=489 cpu_ms=70 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.001975 queue_name=__cron task_name=a449e27ff383de24ff8fc5d5f05f2aae
```

As you can see it makes `GET` request on `/suggestions/`, but nothing happens, including my log messages (they are printed, when I run it second time manually). Do you have any idea, why this might be happening?

My handler:

```
class SuggestionsHandler(RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        logging.debug('Creating suggestions')
        for key in db.Query(User, keys_only=True).order('last_suggestion'):
            make_suggestion(key)
        logging.debug('Done creating suggestions')
        print
        print('Done creating suggestions')
```

This is my cron.yaml:

```
cron:
- description: daily suggestion creation
  url: /suggestions/
  schedule: every 6 hours
```

and proper section of my app.yaml:

```
- url: /suggestions/
    script: cron.py
    login: admin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing this declaration from the bottom of your handler file, after `main`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The first time a handler script is run, App Engine simply imports it, and this snippet runs your main in that situation. On subsequent requests, App Engine runs the `main` function, if you defined one.

Comment: Wow! This is very unexpected. Thanks a lot, good to have a direct support from Google developer on StackOverflow. I will try to fix this in my project tonight ;-)